# Rock paper scissor game in Node JS environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, increment

The game is going to play against the computer, so begin with a function called getComputerChoice that will randomly return either ‘Rock’, ‘Paper’ or ‘Scissors’. We’ll use this function in the game to make the computer’s play.

Write a function that plays a single round of Rock Paper Scissors. The function should take two parameters - the playerSelection and computerSelection - and then return a string that declares the winner of the round like so: "You Lose! Paper beats Rock"

Write a NEW function called game(). Use the previous function inside of this one to play a 5 round game that keeps score and reports a winner or loser at the end.

I have done everything well but I get stuck in the last step which was the incrementation part.
Here is the code:

```js
console.log("Rock Paper Scissor Game");

function getComputerChoice() {
  let words = ["rock", "paper", "scissor"];
  let n = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
  return words[n];
}

function playerRound(playerSelection, computer) {
  let result;
  let computerScore;
  let playerScore;
  let player = playerSelection.toLowerCase();
  if (player === computer) {
    result = "Draw Match";
    computerScore = computerScore;
    playerScore = playerScore;
  } else if (player === 'rock' && computer === 'paper') {
    result = "You Lose ... 'Paper beats Rock'";
    computerScore += 1;
  } else if (player === 'rock' && computer === 'scissor') {
    result = "You Win!!! Rock breaks the scissor";
    playerScore += 1;
  } else if (player === 'paper' && computer === 'rock') {
    result = "Hurray you win!! Paper covers the rock";
    playerScore += 1;

  } else if (player === 'paper' && computer === 'scissor') {
    result = "Oh no you lose.. Scissor cuts the paper";
    computerScore += 1;
  } else if (player === 'scissor' && computer === 'rock') {
    result = "You lose .. Rock breaks the scissor";
    computerScore += 1;
  } else if (player === 'scissor' && computer === 'paper') {
    result = "You win!! Scissor cut the paper";
    playerScore += 1;
  } else {
    result = "You entered wrong  choice";
  }
  return result;
}

function game() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    const playerChoice = prompt("Enter your choice:\n");
    const computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
    console.log(playerRound(playerChoice, computerChoice));
  }
}

game();
```

Comment: There is something weird going on with your arguments. You might want to move the global score to a global context, so you can increment it in `playerRound`, as right now all your data is lost (because you define and edit the data inside the function, but never return its result so it can never be read).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing the score in `playerRound`, but this is not a class, and therefore the variables are reset each function call.

You have a couple of options.

1. Move your `computerScore` and `playerScore` vars outside of the `playerRound` function so they sit inside the top level JS file. This way they will be persisted between function calls, and will require no other changes to your code.
2. Move your `computerScore` and `playerScore` vars to the `game()` function, and pass some sort of state (e.g. `true` for player win, `false` for computer win), which you can then handle and increment the correct score appropriately.

I would recommend option one as it will require the least changes to your code.

Comment: Thank you, now I came to know about the importance of scope the first option is the most viable answer for me...

Thank you for this contribution and continue it

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to organise your code a little differently so you can store the value in a more global scope. I have moved your `game()` function to wrap everything, and run the rounds inside of that individually.

Inside that, we will store `playScore` and `compuerScore` and `playerRound` will update those values. Instead of resetting the `result` variable I also just `return` it after incrementing the score. This is a small optimisation, but it looks easier to read.

```js
function game(){

  function getComputerChoice() {
  
    const words = ["rock", "paper", "scissor"];
    const n = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
    
    return words[n];
    
  }

  function playerRound( playerSelection, computer ){
  
    let player = playerSelection.toLowerCase();
    
    if (player === computer) {
      return "Draw Match";
    } else if (player === 'rock' && computer === 'paper') {
      computerScore += 1;
      return "You Lose ... 'Paper beats Rock'";
    } else if (player === 'rock' && computer === 'scissor') {
      playerScore += 1;
      return "You Win!!! Rock breaks the scissor";
    } else if (player === 'paper' && computer === 'rock') {
      playerScore += 1;
      return "Hurray you win!! Paper covers the rock";
    } else if (player === 'paper' && computer === 'scissor') {
      computerScore += 1;
      return "Oh no you lose.. Scissor cuts the paper";
    } else if (player === 'scissor' && computer === 'rock') {
      computerScore += 1;
      return "You lose .. Rock breaks the scissor";
    } else if (player === 'scissor' && computer === 'paper') {
      playerScore += 1;
      return "You win!! Scissor cut the paper";
    }
    
    return "You entered wrong  choice";
  }

  let computerScore = 0;
  let playerScore = 0;
    
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    const playerChoice = prompt("Enter your choice:\n");
    const computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
    console.log( playerRound(playerChoice, computerChoice) );
  }
  
  console.log({results: {
    computerScore,
    playerScore
  }})

}

game();
```

Answer (score 0):

So first I'd simplify/uniformize `playerRound` so that the return all start the same and match the requirements. I'd also ensure `playerChoice` is valid with a simple loop. Then with a more uniform return from `playerRound` you can check a `slice` to see if you win or lose and increment the correct score.

```js
console.log("Rock Paper Scissor Game");

function getComputerChoice() {
  let words = ["rock", "paper", "scissor"];
  let n = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
  return words[n];
}

function playerRound(playerSelection, computer) {
  let result;
  let player = playerSelection.toLowerCase();
  if (player === computer) {
    result = "Draw Match";
  } else if ((player === 'rock' && computer === 'paper') ||
             (player === 'paper' && computer === 'scissors') ||
             (player === 'scissors' && computer === 'rock')) {
    result = `You Lose ... '${computer} beats ${player}'`;
  } else {
    result = `You Win!!! ${player} beats ${computer}`;
  }
  return result;
}

function game() {
  let playerScore=0;
  let computerScore=0;
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let playerChoice = ''
    while(!['rock','paper','scissors'].includes(playerChoice.toLowerCase())){
        playerChoice = prompt("Enter your choice:\n");
    }
    const computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
    const round = playerRound(playerChoice, computerChoice);
    if (round.slice(0,5) === 'You L') {
       computerScore += 1;
    } else if (round.slice(0,5) === 'You W') {
       playerScore+=1;
    }
    console.log(round);
  }
  if (playerScore>computerScore) {
     console.log('You win the round');
  } else if (playerScore<computerScore) {
     console.log('You lose the round');
  } else {
    console.log("It's a draw");
  }
}

game();
```